# How to pass name of original selectbox to selectize.js load method?

Tags: jquery, html, selectize.js

Using selectize.js,  I'm trying to pass the name-attribute of the select-field to the selectize load-method but can't get my head around it.

Tried so far:

- Catching event of original field (so save name as var) - does not work as original tag is hidden.
- Trying to traverse from the fired load-event, using parent() in various ways but no luck.

.

```
<select name="combo1" class="fa_lookup" placeholder="Type to search..">
   <option value="4">val</option>
</select>
<select name="combo2" class="fa_lookup" placeholder="Type to search...">
   <option value="2">val2</option>
</select>

<script>
//somehow pass the name of the field - how?

$('.fa_lookup').selectize({
    valueField: 'ID', labelField: 'name', searchField: 'name',
    create: false,
    load: function(query, callback) {
        console.log($(this).parent()); // <= No luck
        if (query.length < 2) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getnames.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                name: query,

            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What element does $(this) return?

Comment: Thanks, in console.log, it returns "w.fn.init [w]". Using console.log on variable callback reutrns "w.fn.init [document]"

Comment: You are initializing two select inputs by using a class name as selector for selectize. Is the load function called twice or once? If once then its pretty much impossible to know what te element context is.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. So this means that for lets say 10 different selectize-fields (as in client,user,book,company), I'd need 10 load functions? What I'd like is to pass the name of the field to build the REST-uri:s. Thankful for any clues.

Comment: Try this in the load method
`var element = $(this)[0].$input[0]`